# How to print the index/elements that are included in the final max sum of non-adjacent elements?

Tags: python-3.x

In the program of finding the max sum of non-adjacent elements how can we print the elements/indexes of elements which are considered in the final sum. So here I am attaching my code for that. I am using dynamic programming.

I got the correct answer when there is only one possibility of occurring max sum like we have -1, 2, 4, 5. So the output will be 5 and 2.

```py
n = int(input())
    tickets = list(map(int,input().split()))
    incl = 0
    excl = 0
    max_list = []
    for i in range(len(tickets)): 
        if excl>incl:
            new_excl = excl 
        else:
            new_excl = incl 
        incl = excl + tickets[i]
        excl = new_excl 
        if excl > incl:
            if len(max_list)>1 and (max_list[len(max_list)-1] - max_list[len(max_list)-2])==1:
                del max_list[len(max_list)-2]
        else:
            max_list += [i] 
    if excl>incl:
        print(excl,max_list)
    else:
        print(incl,max_list)
```

But I do not get answers when the input like this : 4, 5, 4, 3. In this input there are two possibilities : 4+4 and 5+3. I want to print that possibility that has a higher digits than the other from right side. So in this example from right side 4 > 3 so the possibility of 4 should be printed. But I got all the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve this problem. This is problem from the techgig's code gladiators qualification round. I find the answer for my problem but anyway this solution doesn't get me 100 marks. I haven't checked it for many test cases but you can check it and if it fails then please inform so I can get what the problem is.

```py
from itertools import combinations
for i in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    tickets = list(map(int,input().split()))
    incl = 0
    excl = 0
    max_list = []
    for i in range(len(tickets)): 
        if excl>incl:
            new_excl = excl 
        else:
            new_excl = incl 
        incl = excl + tickets[i]
        excl = new_excl 
        if excl > incl:
            if len(max_list)>1 and (max_list[len(max_list)-1] - max_list[len(max_list)-2])==1:
                del max_list[len(max_list)-2]
        else:
            max_list += [i] 
    if excl>incl:
        s=excl
    else:
        s=incl
    a=[]
    if 1 in [abs(t-s) for s,t in zip(max_list,max_list[1:])]:
        for m in range(2,n):
            for n in list(combinations(max_list, m)):
                if sum(tickets[b] for b in n)==s:
                    a+=[n]
        l=[]
        index=[]
        for m in a:
            l+=[tickets[m[1]]]
            index+=[m[1]]
        v = index[l.index(max(l))]
        for m in a:
            if v in m:
                ans = m
                break
        for d in list(reversed(ans)):
            print(tickets[d],end='')
        print()
    else:
        max_list.reverse()
        for d in max_list:
            print(tickets[d],end='')
        print()
```